# O que acha sobre sites com conteúdos traduzidos automaticamente para Português do Stack Overflow em Inglês?

Tags: debate

A lot of thanks to [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) for the translation!

---

#### A história do problema

Um ano atrás, os desenvolvedores que falam russo enfrentaram uma ascensão de sites que contêm apenas conteúdo traduzido por máquina do Stack Overflow em inglês. A cada mês, um desses sites soma até um milhão de traduções em seu banco de dados. Existem dezenas desses sites. Por volta desta primavera, esses sites começaram a dominar os resultados de pesquisa em russo em quase todas as consultas. As traduções automáticas nos sites são, na maior parte, de qualidade muito baixa, por isso nem sempre é possível entender o significado do que está escrito lá. Tudo isso causa muita frustração entre os desenvolvedores que falam russo.

#### Como a comunidade russa lidou com o problema?

Após muitas solicitações da comunidade, criamos [uma lista de sites traduzidos por máquina](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/6). Bloqueamos publicações que contenham links para estes sites no Stack Overflow em russo (curiosamente, uma abordagem semelhante é usada na Wikipedia, onde [links externos para suas réplicas são proibidos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Mirrors_and_forks)).

Muitos desenvolvedores não gostam tanto de sites com tradução automática que criaram extensões para o redirecionamento automático para o Stack Overflow em inglês quando acidentalmente acessam um site de tradução automática. Isso funciona para eles, mas muito mais pessoas sofrem. No Stack Overflow em russo, começamos uma [discussão](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8371/6) sobre o que nossa comunidade pode fazer com esse problema. Acreditamos que juntos podemos encontrar uma boa solução para o problema.

#### Como é esse problema em português?

Isso é o que está acontecendo na rede em russo. Você poderia compartilhar sua visão sobre o que está acontecendo com o conteúdo traduzido por máquina do Stack Overflow em inglês no idioma português?

- Você ou seus colegas encontraram sites com conteúdo traduzido do Stack Overflow em inglês? Se sim, qual foi sua experiência? (Se possível, compartilhe links para esses sites nos comentários para essa pergunta.)
- Como você se sente sobre sites com conteúdo traduzido por máquina? Você gosta deles ou considera um problema?
- Se você acha que é um problema, que tipo de solução você sugeriria?

*Por favor, compartilhe sua visão! É um assunto muito importante!*

Comment: I think this isn't a real problem in Portuguese. It's rare to find a website with automatic translation, so much so that I have never found a site that does this

Comment: While I was not able to find any site with Portuguese content yet I was able to find several sites that basically copy the posts from StackOverflow EN without any attribution. Unfortunately I would have to dig in for those sites.

Comment: eu já vi sites traduzidos automaticamente, agora não lembro o nome mas vou pesquisar e escrevo aqui