# Devemos bloquear publicações que contêm links para sites com conteúdo traduzido automaticamente?

Tags: debate

Muito obrigado a [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) pela tradução.

---

Com o crescimento do Stack Overflow em Português, temos visto o surgimento de sites contendo apenas perguntas automaticamente traduzidas do Stack Overflow em Inglês para a língua portuguesa. O problema é que esta tradução automática é, na maioria dos casos, impossível de entender: geralmente não passa de um conjunto de palavras vagamente relacionadas umas às outras.

Defendemos o conhecimento sem fronteiras linguísticas, o conhecimento que é necessário e importante para as pessoas, e que é apoiado pela comunidade. Sites com traduções automáticas são o oposto disso. A meu ver, estes sites não criam nenhum valor e só interferem nos resultados de busca.

Acho que, no Stack Overflow em Português, não deveríamos permitir links para sites com conteúdo traduzido automaticamente, e devemos bloquear postagens contendo tais links, seja impedindo que sejam gravadas, ou mostrando uma mensagem de erro caso alguém tente postá-las:

> Sua publicação contém um link para um site com conteúdo traduzido automaticamente do Stack Overflow em Inglês. Tais sites inteferem nos resultados de busca em português. Por favor use um link para a pergunta original no Stack Overflow em Inglês, ou apague o link.

Por favor, diga o que você acha:

- Devemos bloquear estes sites?
- Em caso afirmativo, qual deveria ser a mensagem de erro?
- Se você conhece estes sites e acha que devemos bloqueá-los, por favor mande uma lista dos endereços

Comment: Relacionada: [O que acha sobre sites com conteúdos traduzidos automaticamente para Português do Stack Overflow em Inglês?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7550/5878)

Comment: E como bloquearíamos estes sites?

Comment: Uma pena essa pergunta ser exclusiva para os moderadores. Pois como usuário tenho opinião formada com relação ao assunto.

Comment: @CypherPotato O mecanismo do site possui um mecanismo que permite verificar cada postagem se ela contém determinados URLs. Tudo o que precisamos é concordar que o fazemos e coletar uma lista de URLs que queremos bloquear.

Comment: @AugustoVasques É uma pergunta para toda a comunidade. Por favor, compartilhe seus pensamentos.

Comment: Eu acho que sites que infringem a licença de conteúdo da Stack Exchange devia ser automaticamente bloqueado a ser supramencionado numa pergunta comunitária, exceto em comunidades meta, porque nelas precisamos discutir sobre.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky on tag instructions state that red tags are exclusive to moderators.That's why I commented.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Eu acho que a descrição da tag diz que a própria tag pode ser usada apenas por moderadores. A pergunta é para todos =)

Comment: @AugustoVasques As "red tags" são de uso exclusivo dos moderadores porque somente eles conseguem **adicionar e remover** esta tags nas perguntas, mas a pergunta em si é para todos.
Nicolas, eu concordo que tem que bloquear, só não conheço nenhum desses sites para indicar. E outra coisa "off-topic": "share your thoughts" em português fica melhor como "compartilhe suas ideias", "dê a sua opinião" ou ainda "diga o que você acha" :-) (os 2 últimos acho que fazem mais sentido no contexto)

Comment: Nicolas e hkotsubo obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Alguém tem algum exemplo prático (caso real ocorrido no  SOpt) do problema que está sendo discutido aqui? Acho que ajudaria a contextualizar melhor.

Comment: @bacco vide pergunta que relacionei esse não parece ser um problema existente no português ainda. O único relatado até agora foi o que o Maniero comentou que traduz português para inglês; o contrário ainda não foi visto.

Comment: @Bacco Esse é o caso há muito tempo no SOru e recentemente se tornou o caso do SOja. Também publiquei no SOpt para ouvir o que a comunidade pensa.

Comment: @hkotsubo desculpe pelo mau uso. Eu traduzi meus comentários no google =D

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Sem problemas, eu também cometo erros parecidos quando escrevo em inglês :-)

Answer (score 5):

Eu penso que **SIM** devemos bloquear esses sites.

No nosso rodapé está disponível esse link [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) que é link para licença Creative Commons. Junto desse link estão escritos:

> contribuições de usuários licenciadas sob [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)

É consenso que o maior bem de um sistema gratuito de uso em rede mundial é o usuário. Mas nós temos um diferencial, que é a veracidade o valor agregado por cada palavra escrita nesse site.

Que façamos valer a licença.

Que protejamos os direitos de nossos usuários, meus direitos também pois sou usuário.

A licença é curta e não apresenta dificuldades em ser seguida. O item da licença que reiteradamente é violado por esses indexadores com tradução é o item relativo a atribuição:

> **Atribuição** - Você deve dar o crédito apropriado , fornecer um link para a licença e indicar se foram feitas alterações . Você pode
>   fazê-lo de qualquer maneira razoável, mas não de maneira que sugira
>   que o licenciante endossa você ou seu uso.

Os tradutores/indexadores citados na [discussão que suscitou esse debate](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8005/este-site-est%C3%A1-atendendo-os-crit%C3%A9rios-do-licenciamento-do-nosso-conte%C3%BAdo), tanto de Português/Inglês e Russo/Inglês, estão violando a licença. E o indexador Russo/Inglês transformou o conteúdo do site em um imenso click-bait.

Os problema que vejo com esses site:

- Tradução automática que é mal feita e modifica a essência da resposta.
- A ausência dos devidos créditos aos elaboradores tanto da pergunta quanto das respostas.

Como solucionar:

- Para replicar o conteúdo traduzido automaticamente o site deve manter de forma visível que foi feita uma tradução mecânica do conteúdo original e também deve conter um link para resposta original.
- Para replicar o conteúdo o site deve creditar adequadamente os autores tanto da pergunta quanto de respostas.

Com relação aos direitos de nós usuários é o que de imediato penso que tem que ser feito.

Answer (score 2):

Eu creio que as publicações, seja pergunta ou resposta, deve ser independente e auto-contida em teu idioma nativo. O Stack Overflow (assim como demais comunidades da SE) confiam em manter o conteúdo aqui no site, e é melhor, porque assim temos todos os recursos e controles sobre o conteúdo publicado.

Nós não temos controle sobre conteúdo externo. [Uma pergunta que depende de outra já está errado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8003/o-que-fazer-com-publica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-que-dependem-de-algo-que-n%C3%A3o-existe-mais?cb=1), mas infelizmente ocorre. Citações não são problemas quando está no conteúdo, e não um link apontando para outro. Repito, nós [comunidade e não autores] não temos controle algum sobre estes conteúdos externos.

### Bloquear não é solução

Eu vejo a restrição como uma barreira para impedir que algo aconteça ao invés de solucionar a raiz do problema, como mencionei nos parágrafos acima. Isso vale para qualquer site, até mesmo estes que contém conteúdo traduzido automaticamente.

Eu particularmente nunca vi uma publicação apontar para um site onde o conteúdo é tão ruim a ponto de ser ilegível. Já vi perguntas referenciarem conteúdos em inglês, mas com legibilidade.

Uma pergunta não há fundamento quando depende de um conteúdo sem fundamento. E perguntas ruins são fechadas. Afinal, perguntas com conteúdo tem respostas com conteúdo, são [verdadeiras](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/507/perguntas-verdadeiras-t%C3%AAm-respostas?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C30.5316).

Além disso, torna incoeso o código linguístico em vincular uma publicação de outro idioma numa publicação de um idioma distinto. Cada comunidade têm um idioma específico e ninguém é obrigado a entender ou traduzir referências doutros idiomas. O ideal é citar, mas traduzir. Assim, não dependeríamos deste link errôneo.

## tl;rd

Eu descarto a ideia de bloqueio porque penso que uma pergunta que dependa de um conteúdo ruim, ilegível ou falso, consequente será uma publicação ruim, sem escopo e brevemente será fechada. É um problema que desvia de um assunto específico mas atinge o mesmo princípio de publicações ruins.